# How to save the row in a variable and save the excel document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The code i use to read the first row of an excel file is this. How to save that row in a string variable before saving? and how to save the excel document?

```
string ExcelFile = Application.StartupPath + @"\SurveyLinks.xlsx";
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFile);
Excel._Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = ExcelWorkBook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range ExcelRange = (Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet.Application.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
ExcelRange.Select();
//string SurveyLink = ExcelRange.Cells[1,1].Value2.ToString();
ExcelRange.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
ExcelWorkBook.Close(true);

ExcelApp.Quit();
MessageBox.Show(SurveyLink);
MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

Answer (score 0):

`WorkBook.Save()` is there to save the excel document 'SaveAs()' also available there.